# How to smooth the border between two different objects

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader-graph, unity3d-shaders

I have two objects, a sea and a river, and each of them with its own shader. In the river delta you can see that they are two different objects and it doesn't look good. Does anyone have any idea what can I do to smooth the edges so that the seam doesn't look that strong? Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Try to search depth texture + water

Comment: Can I get the depth texture using Shader Graph?